# Complex numbers, set of values for which z will be purely real or imaginary.

Tags: complex-numbers, split-complex-numbers

A complex number *z* is given by $ z = \frac{a+i}{a-i}, a∈R$.

- Determine the set of values of *a* such that

(a). *z* is purely real;

(b). *z* is purely imaginary.

(c). Show that |*z*| is a constant for all values of a.

Hi all,

### I solved the question partially - I managed to find that the number will be purely imaginary for *a*=1, and *a*=- 1.
However, when I try to solve for a purely real value, a is undefined.
I think I solved part b, but the proof wasn't all that clear cut and I was hoping you could clarify that a bit for me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $w=a+i$, then $z=\frac{w}{\bar{w}}=\frac{w^2}{w\bar{w}}=\frac{w^2}{|w|^2}$. Since $|w|^2=1+a^2 \in \Bbb{R}$ so you only have to deal with the numerator.

Now $w^2=(a^2-1)+2ai$.

1. For $z$ to be purely imaginary, we want $a^2-1=0 \implies a=\pm 1$.
2. For $z$ to be purely real, we want $2a=0 \implies a=0$.
3. For $|z|$ we have $|z|=\left|\frac{w^2}{|w|^2}\right|=\frac{|w^2|}{|w|^2}=\frac{|w|^2}{|w|^2}=1.$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$z=\frac{a+i}{a-i}=\frac{(a+i)(a+i)}{(a-i)(a+i)}$$

$$=\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}+\frac{2ia}{a^2+1}$$

$z$ is purely real if $2a=0$.

$$|z|^2=\frac{(a+i)(a-i)}{(a-i)(a+i)}=1$$